# Does QML TreeView support signal layoutChanged emitted from model?

Tags: qt, treeview, qml, qabstractitemmodel

I have a model that works well with QTreeView. In the model I implemented a sort that looks like this:

```
void SimpleTreeModel::sort(Node* sortedNode)
{
     emit layoutAboutToBeChanged(QList<QPersistentModelIndex>(), VerticalSortHint);
     QModelIndexList oldIndices = persistentIndexList();

     Node::SortType sortType = Node::Down;

     //sort starting node
     sortedNode->sortChildren(sortType);

     QModelIndexList newIndices;
     newIndices.reserve(oldIndices.size());
     for(const auto &i : oldIndices)
     {
         Node* node = const_cast<Node*>(nodeFromIndex(i));
         QModelIndex index = indexFromNode(node);
         newIndices.push_back(index);
     }
     changePersistentIndexList(oldIndices, newIndices);

     QModelIndex startingIndex = indexFromNode(sortedNode);
     emit layoutChanged({ QPersistentModelIndex(startingIndex) }, VerticalSortHint);
}
```

when I call this function, QTreeView updates the view, but TreeView in QML don't do this.
QML TreeView usage:

```
TreeView
{
    model: treeModel
    TableViewColumn 
    {
        title: "Title"
        role: "title"
        width: 700
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why the view does not update the layout of the elements after sorting?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to delegate the tree view item. Data is provided to delegate.

Try changing your QML **TreeView** as shown below by adding **itemDelegate**

```
TreeView
{
    model: treeModel

    itemDelegate: Item {
       Text {
               color: styleData.textColor
               text: styleData.value
            }
    }

    TableViewColumn 
    {
        title: "Title"
        role: "title"
        width: 700
    }
}
```

Look into below link to understand the importance of delegate, between model and QML view. There is an image which easily explains.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html

> Delegate - dictates how the data should appear in the view. The
>   delegate takes each data in the model and encapsulates it. The data is
>   accessible through the delegate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I can not understand how this should help. The problem is that the TreeView does not respond to signals from the model. After reading the source code of TreeView, I did not find in it the functions responsible for responding to the signal layoutChanged from model. It confused me.

Comment: @strelok.ndv look into this link, you will see an image and how delegate is required to communicate between QML view and model.. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html

Comment: No, I agree with strelok.ndv, delegate has nothing to do with the problem